# How can I use -max-print-line in pdftex (TexLive)?

Tags: pdftex, texlive

I know that Miktex has an option -max-print-line=n to change the width of the output. I wondered if something like that existed for pdftex from TexLive ?

Comment: For instance, on Unix system with a Bash shell one can do `max_print_line=120 pdflatex filename`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your shell is Bourne based (Bash, Zsh) the syntax

```
max_print_line=120 pdflatex filename
```

will do in essentially the same way. The internal variables defined by the `kpathsea` library are superseded if set in the environment.

Alternatively you can add the line

```
max_print_line = 120
```

to the top level `texmf.cnf` file, that is, the one in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012
```

(adjust the number of columns to suit).

Comment: If I had known it was that simple... Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this mean `max_print_line=$COLUMNS pdflatex foo` should automatically do the right thing all the time?

Comment: @RhysUlerich Depends on what you mean by “the right thing” but yes that looks right — actually my preference is to set `max_print_line=10000 pdflatex foo` and leave the line-wrapping up to the terminal. That way, when you resize the terminal window everything gets automatically wrapped to the right length. (Just picked 10000 as an arbitrary large number; so far haven't needed to increase it.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed your TeX Live distribution from the repositories of a Debian- or Ubuntu-based system, you can put a file with your preferred setting in `/etc/texmf/texmf.d`, then run the `update-texmf` command. Both must be performed as root. The setting will be applied globally to all future runs. (**DO NOT** edit files in `/usr/share` directory; you will lose the setting after upgrading TeX.)

To apply it to a single run, you can use an environment variable on the command line, as @egreg explained.

I, for example, use

```
max_print_line=2147483647
```

to effectively disable line wrapping entirely. (After all, it’s my terminal emulator’s job to do it, not TeX’s.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But because I'm working on a `flychecker` and thus cannot use environment variables, nor can change configuration files, I was forced to find a solution that uses arguments.

For `pdflatex`, I was able to add the following argument

```
-cnf-line=max_print_line=1024
```