# output of pdflatex in the command line is too narrow?

Tags: pdftex, terminal-output

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Avoid linebreaks in LaTeX console / log output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52988/avoid-linebreaks-in-latex-console-log-output)

(in the mac) I find quite annoying that for example running:

```
$ /usr/textbin/pdflatex MyDocument.text
```

Results in an 80 characters wide chunk:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./MyDocument.text
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2009-06-19, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian,
 icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, marathi, or
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd)pdfTeX warning (ex
t4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has been already used,
 duplicate ignored
<to be read again>
```

It looks like `pdflatex` breaks its output string before sending it out.
Apparently [TexShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/) has the same problem (since the GUI shows the same issue).
However, [Latexian](http://tacosw.com/latexian/) does show well formatted output so this should be possible. I wonder how can this be done? :)

Some messages/errors/warning are really hard to see in this form.

I have tried the `--help` option and played with some arguments without luck. Is this a missconfiguration of pdflatex or my Terminal/Shell?

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52988/avoid-linebreaks-in-latex-console-log-output or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83600/how-can-i-use-max-print-line-in-pdftex-texlive

Comment: `export max_print_line=1000` was exactly what I was looking for :)