# Avoid splitting/wrapping error message when using pdflatex

Tags: errors, pdftex, compiling

When compiling with `pdflatex` and using the `file-line-error` option if I have a long pathname and there is an error, that error is split at 80 characters in the log file (see image below)

Is one (or both) of the following items possible?

i) force pdflatex to just print the error using the base name (in my example `notas_tdm.tex`) and not the full path?

ii) force pdflatex to show the error message ("Undefined control sequence") in the same line as the (long) file name and line number

[image]

**Edit:** One way to reproduce this behaviour is to use MiKTex on Windows and then write the following MWE in `C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop\foo\bar\baz\a_very_long_directory_name\blah.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\error
\end{document}
```

Running `pdflatex -file-line-error blah.tex` gives the error

```
C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop\foo\bar\baz\a_very_long_directory_name\blah.tex:4: Undef
ined control sequence
```

and the full log is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.2.27)  8 AUG 2014 14:43
entering extended mode
**blah.tex
(C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop\foo\bar\baz\a_very_long_directory_name\blah.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
No file blah.aux.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop\foo\bar\baz\a_very_long_directory_name\blah.tex:4: Undef
ined control sequence
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

(C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop\foo\bar\baz\a_very_long_directory_name\blah.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
199 strings out of 493921
2366 string characters out of 3144876
49031 words of memory out of 3000000
3582 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
23i,1n,17p,128b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: the error messages are generated within the tex engine, which is where the 80-character split occurs, so this may not be possible.  however, if you have the entire path specified in the `\input` or `\include` statement, you might try moving the path to a separate `\pathname` statement.

Comment: That message looks short of some detail: is it exactly what TeX produces (_e.g._ the same as you get from `less <filename>.log`)? Could you copy-paste the appropriate part of the `.log` ile into the question?

Comment: @JosephWright See updated question please. Thank you

Comment: Oh yes, I should've said that I'm using Miktex (I've edited the question to reflect this now). Is it possible to show the relative path with MiKTeX?

Comment: This seems to be MiKTeX-specific: more generally, it adds full paths to the log whereas TeX Live gives relative paths. There's no obvious option to control this: perhaps a feature request might be required?

Comment: @JosephWright If it is really MiKTeX-specific and there is no option to control it then I''ll send a request. However I would like to be completely sure that it is indeed MiKTex-related and there is no possible workaround.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4047/write-to-log-without-wrapping. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83600/how-can-i-use-max-print-line-in-pdftex-texlive

Comment: @egreg Thanks! Setting `!pdflatex -file-line-error -max-print-line=120` effectively works!! How I can pass those options if I use `arara`? I tried `% arara: pdflatex: {action: batchmode, draft: yes, options: "-file-line-error-style -max-print-lines=120"}` but I doesn't work. Can you please post an answer? Thanks again.

Comment: @petobens Sorry, but I know nothing of MiKTeX (and I can't try).

Comment: @egreg That's okay. Do you know (or can directly ask Paulo Cereda) how to pass those two options to arara? I know how to pass a single option by doing: `% arara: pdflatex: {action: batchmode, draft: yes, options: "-file-line-error-style"}` but the problem arises when I try to add the second option (`-max-print-lines`). Thanks agains
 Thanks for the help again?

Comment: As an alternative workaround for this problem in Linux you can pipe the output of pdflatex to `awk '{ printf("%s",$0); if ( length()!=79 ) printf("\n"); }'` to "unsplit" these lines. I'm using this with AUCTeX and emacs compile mode to interpret file:line:error syntax.

Comment: @egreg I had a typo, I was writing `max-print-lines` instead of `max-print-line`. If you want to answer that both `pdflatex -file-line-error -max-print-line=120` and (if arara is used) `% arara: pdflatex: {options: "-file-line-error -max-print-line=120"}` solve my problem then I''ll accept the answer.

Comment: @egreg If you want me to answer the question (I understand you might not want to answer something that you cannot test) then I'll do it. Just let me know. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @petobens Make an answer yourself; note that the option cannot be used with TeX Live, but only with MiKTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one is using MiKTeX then the following can be used when compiling with `pdflatex`:

```
pdflatex -file-line-error -max-print-line=120
```

Note that this will not work with TeX Live.

Thanks to @egreg who gave me this answer in a comment.