# How to change the format of messages in the console window

Tags: warnings, texshop

I am using TeXshop, and I want to know if it is possible to change

1/ the format of these messages (like line spacing, length of lines / line breaking etc.)
in order to be able to focus on readability and optimization of my use of packages.

2/ Is it dependent of my editor or of my latex installation (I am using TexLive) ?

Ps: the previous formulation of this question got me a tumbleweed badge ! And I edited my question after a comment of Barbara Beeton

Comment: since many of the messages are from the tex engine itself, no, it's not possible to change them without redesigning the engine.  but there *are* people looking at that.  (see, for example, [these slides from a presentation at tug 2014](https://tug.org/tug2014/slides/mckenna-JSBox.pdf); a work in progress ...)

Comment: @barbarabeeton thank you for the link ! Part of my question is about the formatting of the messages in the console window of the Texshop editor on macosx. Does somebody know a way to access the number of columns displayed in each row of this console and change it ??

Comment: You could write a script to filter the output into whatever form you might like; but otherwise you'd have to change the engine.

Comment: There is the package `silence` which allows some control over what kinds of information is reported in the logs.  It should be used with some care as you may actually hide an essential piece of information needed to debug a problem.  The documentation is at http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/silence/silence-doc.pdf.  The major value here is to silence unwanted and unneeded log entries generated by selected packages, especially if they are very *chatty*.

Comment: @R.Schumacher you are perfectly right. That is why I am not looking for a way to change the content of the informations provided by \Tex but a way to change their formatting in the console window of my editor. Namely I want each message to be on one long line not on several which make the reading too difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of TeX log entries defaults to a fixed 80 columns.  In TeXShop there is a preference to allow you to arbitrarily change the width and height of the console (in the Console panel of the preferences). If you make the console wider than the default, you can use the full 80 columns, which will put most but not all output on single lines.

You can change the value of the maximum output lines using the technique shown here:

[How can I use -max-print-line in pdftex (TexLive)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83600/how-can-i-use-max-print-line-in-pdftex-texlive)

Comment: The 80 column value is a run-time setting so can be altered from `texmf.cnf`: it's not hard-coded in TeX.

Comment: @JosephWright Cool, I didn't know that.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: @JosephWright Quite cool indeed, if I can actually alter it. I looked into texmf.cnf but I did not see any obvious parameter. Can you explain how I can do it ?

Comment: @AlanMunn At last somebody understood me ! What I want is really to overcome the 80 columns limit !

Comment: @brunoh See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83600/how-can-i-use-max-print-line-in-pdftex-texlive

Comment: @JosephWright Following the link given by egreg I managed to change the number of columns to 160 : all the messages from the engine are now neatly on one line making the output much more readable. Can you make your comment an answer and I can accept it ?

Comment: @egreg +1 with your link I managed to do that JosephWright suggested. And I realized that perhaps my question is a bit like a duplicate ...